# Verilog Error when I try to access the output value of another module

Tags: verilog

I have written the following code in verilog:

```
module memory
    #(
        parameter RAM_WIDTH         = 12,
        parameter RAM_ADDR_BITS     = 3,
        parameter INIT_START_ADDR   = 0,
        parameter INIT_END_ADDR     = 7
    )
    (
    input                           clock,
    input                           ram_enable,
    input                           write_enable,
    input       [RAM_ADDR_BITS-1:0] address,
    input       [RAM_WIDTH-1:0]     input_data,
    output reg  [RAM_WIDTH-1:0]     output_data
    );
    
   
   (* RAM_STYLE="BLOCK" *)
   reg [RAM_WIDTH-1:0] ram_name [(2**RAM_ADDR_BITS)-1:0];

   initial begin
      ram_name[0] = 12'b000000000000;
      ram_name[1] = 12'b000001010000;
      ram_name[2] = 12'b000011001000;
      ram_name[3] = 12'b000101101101;
      ram_name[4] = 12'b000101101101;
      ram_name[5] = 12'b001100100011;
      ram_name[6] = 12'b010001001100;
      ram_name[7] = 12'b011001110110;
   end

   // always @(ram_enable or write_enable or address or input_data) begin
   always @ ( * ) begin
      if (ram_enable) begin
         if (write_enable)
            ram_name[address] = input_data;
         output_data = ram_name[address];
      end
    // $strobe("output_data is %d", output_data);
   end

endmodule


// Design
// Information Bottleneck Quantizer
module get_quantizer_output (clk, rst, ch_output, boundary_1, boundary_2, boundary_3, boundary_4, boundary_5, boundary_6, boundary_7, boundary_8, cluster_index_val);
  input clk, rst;
  
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_1;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_2;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_3;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_4;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_5;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_6;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_7;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_8;
  

  input wire signed [11:0] ch_output;
  reg [11:0] ch_output_mag;
  output reg [3:0] cluster_index_val;
  

  
  // always @(ch_output) begin
  always @ ( * ) begin
    if (ch_output[11] == 1) begin
      ch_output_mag = ~ch_output + 1; 
     
    end else begin
      ch_output_mag = ch_output;
    end
    
    $strobe("boundary_1 is %d", boundary_1);
    $strobe("boundary_2 is %d", boundary_2);
    $strobe("boundary_3 is %d", boundary_3);
    $strobe("boundary_4 is %d", boundary_4);
    $strobe("boundary_5 is %d", boundary_5);
    $strobe("boundary_6 is %d", boundary_6);
    $strobe("boundary_7 is %d", boundary_7);
    $strobe("boundary_8 is %d", boundary_8);
    
    // $strobe("channel output is %d", ch_output);
    // $strobe("ch_output_mag is %d", ch_output_mag);
    
    
    
    
    if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_5) begin
    
      // $strobe("value less than or equal to  boundary_5");
      
      if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_3) begin
        // $strobe("value less than or equal to boundary_3");
        if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_2) begin
         
          // $strobe("value less than or equal to boundary_2");
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0111 : 4'b1000;
        end else begin
          // $strobe("value greater than boundary_2");
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0110 : 4'b1001;
        end
      end else begin
        
        if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_4) begin
          // $strobe("value less than or equal to boundary_4");
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0101 : 4'b1010;
        end else begin
          // $strobe("value greater than boundary_4");
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0100 : 4'b1011;
          end
        end
     
    end else begin
      
      if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_7) begin
        // $strobe("value less than or equal to boundary_7");
        if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_6) begin
          // $strobe("value less than or equal to boundary_6");
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0011 : 4'b1100;
        end else begin
          // $strobe("value greater than boundary_6");
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0010 : 4'b1101;
        end
      end else begin
        
        if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_8) begin
          // $strobe("value less than or equal to boundary_8");
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0001 : 4'b1110;
        end else begin
          // $strobe("value greater than boundary_8");
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0000 : 4'b1111;
        end
      end
    
    
    end 
    
    $strobe("cluster_index_val is %d", cluster_index_val);
  end
    
  
endmodule


module ibq (clk, rst, ch_output, cluster_index_out);

  input clk, rst;
  output [3:0] cluster_index_out;
  input wire signed [11:0] ch_output;

  
  wire [11:0] boundary1;
  wire [11:0] boundary2;
  wire [11:0] boundary3;
  wire [11:0] boundary4;
  wire [11:0] boundary5;
  wire [11:0] boundary6;
  wire [11:0] boundary7;
  wire [11:0] boundary8;
  
  
  
  memory memory1 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b000), .output_data(boundary1));
  memory memory2 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b001), .output_data(boundary2));
  memory memory3 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b010), .output_data(boundary3));
  memory memory4 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b011), .output_data(boundary4));
  memory memory5 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b100), .output_data(boundary5));
  memory memory6 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b101), .output_data(boundary6));
  memory memory7 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b110), .output_data(boundary7));
  memory memory8 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b111), .output_data(boundary8));
  
 
  get_quantizer_output get_quantizer_output0 (.clk(clk), .rst(rst), .ch_output(ch_output), .boundary_1( boundary1), .boundary_2( boundary2), .boundary_3( boundary3), .boundary_4( boundary4), .boundary_5( boundary5), .boundary_6( boundary6), .boundary_7( boundary7), .boundary_8( boundary8), .cluster_index_val(cluster_index_out));
  $strobe("cluster_index_out is %d", cluster_index_out); 

endmodule


module ibq_test (clk, rst, cluster_index_out);
  input clk, rst;
  output [3:0] cluster_index_out;
  wire signed [11:0] ch_output_test = 12'b000100110011;
  ibq ibq0 (.clk(clk), .rst(rst), .ch_output(ch_output_test), .cluster_index_out(cluster_index_out));


endmodule
```

In the above code, when I try to print the value of cluster_index_out that I get as an output from the get_quantizer_output module inside ibq module, I get the following error:

```
jdoodle.v:176: syntax error
jdoodle.v:176: error: invalid module item.
```

If I comment the statement  `$strobe("cluster_index_out is %d", cluster_index_out);` statement that I have written in ibq module code works and I get the correct value as I have expected. Why I am experiencing this behaviour? Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

System tasks that extract data, like `$monitor` need to be in an initial or always block [[1](https://www.iitg.ac.in/hemangee/cs224_2020/verilog1.pdf)].

Enclosing the `$strobe` within always block seems to fix this? https://www.edaplayground.com/x/B7fB

```
 ...
  get_quantizer_output get_quantizer_output0 (.clk(clk), .rst(rst), .ch_output(ch_output), .boundary_1( boundary1), .boundary_2( boundary2), .boundary_3( boundary3), .boundary_4( boundary4), .boundary_5( boundary5), .boundary_6( boundary6), .boundary_7( boundary7), .boundary_8( boundary8), .cluster_index_val(cluster_index_out));
  always @(*) begin 
    $strobe("cluster_index_out is %d", cluster_index_out);
  end
...
endmodule
```

Comment: Please put code, not link.

Comment: Is the link inaccessible? No need to sign up/sign in to try running the code, I think.

Comment: Now code is accessible. But no one knows if the code will be accessible in future. No one likes when answer redirects to 404.

Comment: Ah! I get it. I will fix that. Thanks. Also Thanks for confirming that it is accessible.